# Magento 2 Why Credit memo reund tax from shipping cost?

Tags: magento2, tax, creditmemo, shipping-tax

When create a **Credit memo**, I don't want to credit the Shipping cost, So in the field Refund Shipping, I just write 0. but system still refund the tax part of the shipping cost.

For example, if the shipping cost is 7 USD, and in the credit memo i write 0 in Refund shipping, the system will still refund 20% of the tax which is 1.4 USD.

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Magento 2.2.7 and is fixed in Magento 2.2.10. The error never appears when I upgraded the site to 2.2.10.